# SwiftUI submitLabel not working on TextEditor

Tags: input, swiftui

I want to use `.submitLabel` to change the "return" key to something else (namely, `.done`) but it does not appear to work with the TextEditor input form. Is it supposed to?

Sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .submitLabel(.search)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What evidence I can see points to a bug. No warnings or errors but doesn't work under iOS15 and Xcode 13.1. Meanwhile Hacking With Swift specifically mentions TextEditor as working with it in Xcode 13.2 under iOS15 https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-customize-the-submit-button-for-textfield-securefield-and-texteditor .  Might be worth giving the beta 13.2 download a try.

Comment: Would this involve re-installing xcode? I've never worked with the beta version of xcode before

Comment: Yes, but can keep existing released installation as well. And, fwiw, only problem I had running in parallel during the Xcode 12.X and Beta 13.0  period was with an Xcode formatting extension that got confused and would stop working when new updates arrived. Apple's Beta details/instructions here https://developer.apple.com/support/beta-software/ . Could also try giving HWS a ping to confirm before proceeding.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

### Upcoming Support

- Support was added in Xcode 13.2 beta 3, which is not yet available.

### Temporary Fix

Ok, so based on my attempts, `.submitLabel(...)` doesn't function with TextEditor. There is a possible solution where you add a `Text(...)` as a subview to the `TextEditor(...)` but that is extremely jenk and I wouldn't recommend that. There is however a solution I found for iOS 13 that seems to function the exact same way that the TextEditor appears to work and that's to use `UIViewRepresentable`. Thankfully it's very easy to implement. Create this struct.

```
struct TextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewType = UITextView
    var configuration = { (view: UIViewType) in }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIViewType {
        UIViewType()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) {
        configuration(uiView)
    }
}
```

Then use that view as you would use a `TextView()` where you assign its properties. This is effectively pulling over the `UIKit` version of a textView, so its properties will be the same. You can get fancy with it at this point and mix SwiftUI and UIKit properties and modifiers.

```
    TextView { view in
        view.text = sampleText
        view.returnKeyType = .done
    }
```

Comment: Is there downside to it being an iOS 13 solution? The rest of my project is targeted at iOS 15.

Comment: The only "Downside" is having to deal with UIViewRepresentable but it seems to be the easiest solution. You have the option to create your own custom view that utilizes `Text(...)` and use `@ViewBuilder` to build a view as you go, but I get the feeling that is too much effort for what it's worth.

Comment: @xTwisteDx: Is there any reason using `UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>`instead of `Context`?

Comment: `.submitLabel` and `onSubmit` still not working on xcode 13.2.1, do you know why? @xTwisteDx

Comment: @JoeL you have some other issue if you're on XCode 13.2.X and it's not working. I verified myself that it is indeed there.

Comment: Helpful answer...However, the submit button says "done", but pressing it still creates a new line instead of dismissing the keyboard... any fixes?

Answer (score 2):

Although I have no evidence, I would think that since Apple defines a TextEditor as:
"A text editor view allows you to display and edit multiline, scrollable text in your app’s user interface",
The "Return" key is needed for line feeds, and may therefore not be able to be affected by .submitLabel

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/texteditor